# different result from 1 // -2 and int(1 / -2) in python3

Tags: python-3.x

i'm seeing a different result from 2 different division method for the same formula.

`1 // -2` will give -1

however

`int(1 / -2)` will give 0

I've been searching python division question but didn't see anything related to a division between a position number and negative number. any thoughts on this one?

Comment: So why did you use `//` ? (hint: I know what that operator does, do you?) Also, it is important to know what you expected, did you expect the first to give 0 or the second to give -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't do the same thing. `//` floors the result, while `int` rounds toward 0. The difference is subtle but important.

```
In [251]: 1 / -2
Out[251]: -0.5

In [252]: 1 // -2
Out[252]: -1
```

Versus,

```
In [253]: int(1 / -2)
Out[253]: 0
```

The difference is more apparent with negative numbers, where `int` would round *up* (because it rounds to `0`) whereas `//` (floor division) rounds down regardless.

Comment: by saying floor division, you mean that since `1 / -2 ` should give -0.5 and -1 is less than -0.5, that's why the result floors to -1, is it correct?

Comment: @RyanZhu yes. The result is rounded _down_ (or floored).